# Input value not changing on setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Working with React, in my function setTitleAndBody that you can see below, when I console.log the object *result* I get the title and body information displayed in the developer pannel but the setState is not working and I can't find out why. Maybe something is interacting with it so it cannot be displayed in my input sections but I can't seem to find it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

class TextEditor extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      noteTitre: '',
      noteCorps: ''
    };

    this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBodyChange = this.handleBodyChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.clearInput = this.clearInput.bind(this);
    this.setTitleAndBody = this.setTitleAndBody.bind(this);
  }

  handleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({noteTitre: event.target.value});
  }

  handleBodyChange(event) {
    this.setState({noteCorps: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    let postData = {
      title: this.state.noteTitre,
      body: this.state.noteCorps
    }

    var dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
    dbRef.push(postData);

    this.setState({noteTitre: ""});
    this.setState({noteCorps: ""});

    alert("Note sauvegardée!")
  }

  clearInput() {
    this.setState({noteTitre: ""});
    this.setState({noteCorps: ""});
  }

  setTitleAndBody(result) {
    console.log(result)
    this.setState({noteTitre: result.title});
    this.setState({noteCorps: result.body});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="writing">
        <div className="form-group">

          {/* Titre */}
          <input
            name="noteTitre"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Titre de la note"
            value={this.state.noteTitre}
            onChange={this.handleTitleChange} />

          <br/>

          {/* Corps */}
          <textarea
            name="noteCorps"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Corps de la note"
            value={this.state.noteCorps}
            onChange={this.handleBodyChange} />

        </div>

        <div className="text-right">

          {/* Bouton d'annulation */}
          <button
            onClick={this.clearInput}
            className="btn btn-danger mr-2 rounded">
              Annuler
          </button>

          {/* Bouton de sauvegarde */}
          <button
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}
            className="btn btn-success ml-2 rounded"
            id="bouton_sauvegarde">
              Sauvegarder
          </button>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TextEditor;
```

Comment: Did you try console.log(this.state) to see if setState is really not setting state?
If this.state changes, setState works.

Comment: @SirOneOfMany Thanks for the idea, I tried it after my two this.setState and it didn't change! My variables are still empty. Really don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

I did not see where you use setTitleAndBody in this code.
And how do you know that state is not change?
How you test it?

if you decide that is not changed because printing with console.log(this.state) it is not gonna work, because setState is asynchronous.

you can provide the console.log as callback to setState. `setState(updater, callback)` to see the right value.

`setTitleAndBody(result) { this.setState({noteTitre: result.title}, () => console.log(this.state)); ........ }`

Comment: Thank you, I can now confirm that it's really not working.

Answer (score 0):

destructuring title and body will solve the problem,

better approach:

```
  setTitleAndBody(result) {
    const {title, body} = result;
    this.setState({...this.state, noteTitre:title, noteCorps:body });
  }
```

follow above approach every where you are setting a state such as:

```
 handleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({...this.state, noteTitre: event.target.value});
  }

  handleBodyChange(event) {
    this.setState({...this.state, noteCorps: event.target.value});
  }
``
```

Comment: It's sadly not working. Well the program still runs but I still can't change my input value. But thanks! We didn't have a lot of time but even my teacher didn't get why it's not working.